# how to transform a string into a factor and sets contrasts using dplyr/magrittr piping

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

i have a rather specific question: how can I make a string into a factor and set its contrasts within a pipe ?

Let's say that I have a tibble like the following

```
tib <- data_frame (a = rep(c("a","b","c"),3, each = T), val = rnorm(9))
```

Now, I could use then two separate lines

```
tib$a <- factor(tib$a)
contrasts(tib$a) <- contr.sum(3)
```

But what If I wanted to perform the same actions within a pipe from dplyr ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this was a fun puzzle, since I never used do() before, but this works for me:

```
tib <- data.frame (a = rep(c("a","b","c"),3, each = T), val = rnorm(9)) 

tib = tib %>% mutate(a = factor(a)) %>% do({function(X) {contrasts(X$a) <- contr.sum(3); return(X)}}(.))

contrasts(tib$a)
```

result:

```
  [,1] [,2]
a    1    0
b    0    1
c   -1   -1
```

Hope this helps!

> EDIT: Comment request for explanation, see below:

This was also new for me. As I understand it, within the do() call, it says

```
{func}(.)
```

this means that a function should be called, with argument ., which is the dataframe in a do call. within func, we then specify the function as

```
function(X) {operation to perform on X}
```

so adding this together:

```
{function(X) {operation to perform on X}}(.)
```

Which means . is used as argument in function X, so it basically becomes *'operation to perform on .'*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
Would you mind tear down a bit the do call for me ?
I am not sure why there are two accolades.

Comment: No problem, I liked the puzzle. Would you consider accepting my answer (checkmark below votes)? Thanks!

Comment: edited the answer, since you requested for some explanation. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, now is indeed more clear! And it worked as a charm, so answer accepted!
Your example of do use will be certainly of great help to me in the future !

Answer (score 7):

Everything in R is a function. You just have to know what it's called. In this case, it's `contrasts<-` to assign contrasts to a factor.

```
mutate(tib, a=`contrasts<-`(factor(a), , contr.sum(3)))
```

Comment: Ah! I knew that putting something in `` works to make it a function, but I didn't know this was so extensive. Is it a regular feature ? What I mean is: can I create "pipe friendly version" of any function just following the pattern `name_of_the_function<-` ?
And what the empty space between the two commas stand for in your post ?

Comment: Nearly all the time, yes.

Comment: This is so changing my game that I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: Note that this solution may not work on grouped data.